# I have created a SDK to be used with Android Apps for tracking events, How to know the size of this SDK?

Tags: android, sdk

Is it the same as the .jar or .aar files. The current .aar files we created has size of around 250 kb. Is this what I call as SDK size or is it the size added to an APK file when I include this SDK.

Comment: ???? really you created new Android SDK? Please update your question to be clear.

Comment: For some event tracking, we created an SDK to be used with Android Apps